# Is it possible to have class members of an anonymous class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, anonymous-class

I'm trying to create a class that has fields in it that are of an anonymous type. (This is for Json deserialization.)

I can't find a syntax that the compiler will accept. I'm trying:

```
class Foo {
    var Bar = new {
        int num;
    }
    var Baz = new {
        int[] values;
    }
}
```

This is supposed to represent this example Json object:

```
{
    "Bar": { "num": 0 }
    "Baz": { "values": [0, 1, 2] }
}
```

Is this even possible, or must I declare each class normally with a full class identifier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* declare a field using an anonymous type initializer... you *can't* use implicit typing (`var`). So this works:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static object x = new { Name = "jon" };

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

... but you can't change the type of `x` to `var`.

Comment: Yep, that works (in my case without `static` on `x`). I assume I cannot declare a type for `Name`, but have to assign initial values instead for the compiler to infer the type?

Comment: @NikosC.: Yes, you have to assign a value (and anonymous types in C# are immutable); the compiler infers the type of the property from that value.

Comment: Hm, how do I access the members though? This doesn't work: `Test test = new Test; test.x.Name = "";`

Comment: @NikosC.: No, it wouldn't. You could use dynamic typing if you really must, or reflection... but basically anonymous types aren't designed for use as fields. You don't get most of the benefits without implicit typing.

Comment: Ah, that's a bummer. I was used to the C++ way of doing this (`struct Test { struct { string Name; } x; };` you then can just do: `Test test; test.x.Name = "";`). Too bad C# doesn't allow this. It's more practical to just fully declare the classes then instead of dealing with runtime reflection (or any other runtime mechanism.) I was hoping to cut down on identifier pollution with all the classes that no one will use directly and therefore don't actually deserve a name.

Comment: @NikosC. You can use inner private classes to reduce identifier pollution.  You can use partial classes if you prefer such inner classes to be in a separate file.  You can also use `EditorBrowsableAttribute` to hide public classes from Intellisense, though such hiding only works for consumers of your class (sensibly, the attribute is ignored when consuming your own code).

Comment: @Brian That doesn't work. The fields of those classes must be public and accessible outside the class (and also outside the namespace and assembly.) If I use private inner classes, their fields are not accessible. In other words, I cannot declare a public field that is of a private type.

Comment: You can still use inner public classes and you can still use `EditorBrowsableAttribute`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, here is [EXAMPLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FR3oIW)

```
var Bar = new {num = 0};

var Baz = new {values = new List<int>()};

var Foo = new {Bar, Baz};

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Foo));
```

Of Course you can type it in one line

```
var Foo = {Bar = new {num = 0}, Baz = new {values = new List<int>()}};
```

**Edit** updated .Net fiddle with using Foo as class

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. The most straightforward way to do this is to simply create classes like you said. This is what I'd recommend.

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Foo { Bar = new Bar {
        num = 0
    },
    Baz = new Baz { values = new[] { 0, 1, 2 } }
    })); // {"Bar":{"num":0},"Baz":{"values":[0,1,2]}}

}
public class Foo {
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
    public Baz Baz { get; set; }
}
public class Bar {
    public int num { get; set; }
}
public class Baz {
    public int[] values { get; set; }
}
```

Another approach, which loses static type checking, is typing it as `object` or `dynamic`:

```
void Main()
{
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Foo { Bar = new {
        num = 0
    },
    Baz = new { values = new[] { 0, 1, 2 } }
    }); // {"Bar":{"num":0},"Baz":{"values":[0,1,2]}}

}
class Foo {
    public object Bar { get; set; }
    public object Baz { get; set; }
}
```

It would probably be possible to write a custom [`JsonConverter`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) to serialize a class like this as you wish (since each anonymous type in your example only has one real value inside it; if your real types are more complex, this won't work for those).

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyFooConverter))]
class Foo {
    public int Bar { get; set; }
    public int[] Baz { get; set; }
}
```